# JS Algorthim - CodeCamp

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

wonder if you could help me understand this a little further; tried to use the debugger and various console logs to see where it's failing but still not entirely sure.

---

Make a function that looks through an array of objects (first argument) and returns an array of all objects that have matching name and value pairs (second argument). Each name and value pair of the source object has to be present in the object from the collection if it is to be included in the returned array.

For example, if the first argument is [{ first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" }, { first: "Mercutio", last: null }, { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }], and the second argument is { last: "Capulet" }, then you must return the third object from the array (the first argument), because it contains the name and its value, that was passed on as the second argument.

---

Below is the code not working on the given function below; it should return the following:

```json
[{ "apple": 1, "bat": 2, "cookie": 2 }]
```

However, all three objects are returned instead of just the one.

p.s. excuse the variable naming convention

```js
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
  const arr = [];

  collection.filter(function (obj) {
    const objKeysInSrc = Object.keys(source);

    objKeysInSrc.every(function (keyVal) {
      console.log(keyVal);
      console.log(obj[keyVal]);
      console.log(source[keyVal]);

      console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty(keyVal));

      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(keyVal) && obj[keyVal] === source[keyVal]) {
        console.log("match");
        arr.push(obj);
      }
    });
  });
  console.log(arr);
  return arr;
}

whatIsInAName(
  [{ apple: 1, bat: 2 }, { bat: 2 }, { apple: 1, bat: 2, cookie: 2 }],
  { apple: 1, bat: 2 }
);
```

Now this code below works perfectly fine

```js
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) { 
  const filtArr = collection
    .filter(prop => Object.keys(source)
    .every(value => prop
    .hasOwnProperty(value) && prop[value] === source[value]));
 
  return filtArr;
}
```

I'm curious to know what could be wrong here as the given test cases work but others fail.

This given function call works:

```js
whatIsInAName(
  [
    { first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" },
    { first: "Mercutio", last: null },
    { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" },
  ],
  { last: "Capulet" }
);
```

Comment: Could you start your question with a paragraph that explains what the code challenge is about?

Comment: Updated the thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not correctly using array methods:

- The callback to `filter` should *return* whether the current item should be included or not, and `filter` will *return* a new array that has the included items. So you need:

  - To `return` something in the callback
  - Capture the array that is returned by `.filter`.
- The callback to `every` should *return* whether the current item is OK or not, and `every` will *return* a boolean whether *all* items are OK or not. So you need:

  - To `return` something in the callback
  - Capture the boolean that is returned by `.every`
- The callback to `every` currently pushes an item to `arr` when just one key matches, but:

  - You should only retain an object when *every* key of the source object is present, not just one
  - Using `arr.push` inside a `every` (or `filter`) callback is an anti-pattern. The idea is that you use whatever these methods *return*.

The correct solution that you posted, does all these things right.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this, was helpful. Managed to get it working

```
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
 
  const newCollection = collection
    .filter(function(obj) { 
      return Object.keys(source)
      .every(function(keyVal) { 
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(keyVal) && obj[keyVal] === source[keyVal]) {
          return obj;
      }
    })
  })
  return newCollection;
}
```

Comment: Or as a one-liner: `const whatIsInAName = (collection, source) => collection .filter (obj => Object .entries (source) .every (([k, v]) => obj [k] === v))`.  There is a minor inefficiency here (and in yours) of parsing the key/values from your source on every iteration of `filter`.  This would not be hard to fix.